# ALM Octane UFT Discovery Job not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft, opentext, uft14

I am working on Octane and UFT integration and I an facing a issue on the UFT Test discovery job from SCM in Jenkins. The discovery jobs runs has 2 parameters - one is full sync and other is changeset sync. Difference in both is in full sync it scan the whole SCM repo and update every test case and in ChangeSet Sync it only scan for changes and update if any.

Now, my job is getting failed in ChangeSet Sync with the null error.

I have gone through Jenkins plugin docs also but nothing is there.

Any solution to it would be appreciated.

[image: Error screenshot]

The expected behaviour would be that in ChangeSet Sync it should run fine.